# MySQL: разбивка временного интервала на участки в несколько минут

Tags: запрос, mysql

Есть на входе дата. И есть другая дата как начало отсчёта.
Время разбивается на интервалы по 10 15 30 минут и т д. Нужно узнать в какой по счету от начальной даты промежуток 10 15 30 минут попала датавремя на входе, и датавремя начала и конца этого периода.

Запрос на mysql.

Comment: Вычтите из входной даты начало отсчёта, выразите в минутах и поделите на 15.

Comment: А как взять начало и конец периода?  Помогите з запросом, я вроде понимаю идею, а надо выразить её:)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN your_date BETWEEN someDate AND someDate + 15min THEN 1
WHEN your_date BETWEEN someDate + 15 min 01 sec AND someDate + 30 min THEN 2
WHEN your_date > someDate + 30 min 01 sec THEN 3 END AS num_interval FROM some_table
```

Функции работы с датами смотрите в документации по MySQL

Comment: И сколько случаев вы собираетесь прописать вручную?

Comment: Конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос. Нужно узнать в какой по счету от начальной даты промежуток 10 15 30 минут попала. Какой вопрос такой ответ.

Comment: Не подходит, мне надо не только три промежутка:)

Answer (score 0):

Для 15-минутного интервала запрос может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
SELECT
  FLOOR(
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-10 15:00:00')) / (15 * 60)
  ) AS begin_15,
  CEILING(
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-10 15:00:00')) / (15 * 60)
  ) AS finish_15,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-10 15:00:00') + 
    FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-10 15:00:00')) / (15 * 60)) *
    (15 * 60)
  ) AS date_begin_15,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-10 15:00:00') + 
    CEILING((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-10 15:00:00')) / (15 * 60)) *
    (15 * 60)
  ) AS date_finish_15;
+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| begin_15 | finish_15 | date_begin_15       | date_finish_15      |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    20579 |     20580 | 2016-05-11 23:45:00 | 2016-05-12 00:00:00 |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Дата отсчета выбрана '2015-10-10 15:00:00', в качестве проверяемой даты берется текущая. Для других интервалов цифру в запросе следует заменить цифру 15 на цифру, соответствующую количеству минут в интервале.